# Two or more tables side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add at least another table next to the one in this code, any help appreciated?

```
> <div id="view0"></div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#view0').csv2table('./CSVFiles/CallsClosedbyDept.csv');
});
</script>
```

The code loads a csv and displays it as table and I would like to add another CSV file as a table but instead of below the first table I would like them to be side by side. the full code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head><style>
div.csv2table-div {
  padding           : 5px; 
  margin            : 1px;
}
table.csv2table-table {
  border-collapse   : collapse;
  border-spacing    : 0px;
  margin-bottom     : 10px;
}
th.csv2table-table-th{
  border-color      : #eee #999 #777 #bbb;
  border-style      : solid;
  border-width      : 1px;
  background-color  : red; 
  padding           : 8px;
  font-size         : 16px;
  color         : white;
  text-align        : center;
}
td.csv2table-table-td{
  border-color      : #eee #999 #777 #bbb;
  border-style      : solid;
  border-width      : 1px;
  padding           : 8px;
  font-size         : 14px;
  text-align        : center;
}


td.csv2table-table-td:nth-child(1){
  background-color  : blue;
  color         : white;
}

th.csv2table-sortMark{

}
td.csv2table-hoboNum{

}
</style><title>Calls Closed by Department or Depot</title></head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: left;"><div style="text-align: left;"><img style="width: 130px; height: 76px;" alt="" src="file://///vm-spiceworks/e$/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/Spiceworks/pkg/gems/spiceworks_public-7.1.00024/photos/Hire%20Solutions-01.jpg"><br></div><big style="font-weight: bold;"><big><big><br><span style="color: rgb(51, 0, 153);">Calls Closed by Department or Depot May 2014</span><br><br></big></big></big>
</div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.csv2table-0.02-b-4.7.js"></script>


<script>
  $.csv2table.cssReset();
</script>



<div id="view0"></div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#view0').csv2table('./CSVFiles/CallsClosedbyDept.csv');
});
</script>




<br>
&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(51, 0, 153);">Confidential and `Proprietary</span></body></html>`
```

Comment: can you brief more on this?

Comment: can you please share at least relevant code so that we can figure out the problem or share SJSfiddle

Comment: Place another `div` next to current one and use `csv2table` for that one too.

Comment: Hi Batu Zet I tried placing another div next to current one but it just shows the table below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this structure

```
<div style="border:1px #ccc solid">

<div style="width:45%; float:left; min-height:300px;">
1st table code here
</div>

<div style="width:45%; float: right; min-height:300px;">
2nd table code here
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers fahd4007, I also found a solution but yours looks lbetter, my solution is below.                                                              


    <table cellpadding="30" width="100%"> 
    
    <tr> 
    
    <td> 
    
    
    <div id="view0"></div>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $('#view0').csv2table('./CSVFiles/CallsClosedbyDept.csv');
    });
    </script>
    
    </td> 
    <td> 
    
    <div id="view1"></div>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $('#view1').csv2table('./CSVFiles/CallsClosedbyDept.csv');
    });
    </script>

Comment: fahd4007 is it possible to add titles to the columns?

Comment: @JohnBrines i don't know which language you are using to show data.
also have no experience in any languages other then 6month in c# .net
i m a UI developer and designer
may be if you post all your code may be i'll try to see it :)
and show me the screenshot

Comment: I solved the title by using a caption, all is working finr now, thanks all for the help.